# Display Link in XSLT Mega Menu Dropdown

Tags: xml, xslt, href, megamenu

I am trying to add a div at the bottom of my xslt mega menu code to display a hyperlink 'View All' button/call to action but can't get anything to display. My xslt code is as follows:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:output method="html"/>
      <xsl:param name="ControlID" />
      <xsl:param name="Options" />

  <xsl:param name="subMenuColumns">1</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="subpointer"><![CDATA[]]></xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="pointer"><![CDATA[]]></xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="startUl"><![CDATA[<ul>]]></xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="endUl"><![CDATA[</ul>]]></xsl:param>
  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="root" />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="root">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function splitSubMenu(columns) {
      jQuery("div.sub").each(function (i) {
      if (i==1) {
      columns=4;
      } else {
      columns=4;
      }
      var items = jQuery(this).find('ul');
      var blockCount = columns;
    </script>
    <ul class="megamenu" id="megamenu">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node">
        <xsl:with-param name="level" select="0"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="node">
    <xsl:param name="level" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$level=0">
        <li>
          <xsl:attribute name="class">
            level0 <xsl:if test="@breadcrumb = 1">current</xsl:if>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <a>
            <xsl:attribute name="class">
              level0 <xsl:if test="@breadcrumb = 1">current</xsl:if>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="@enabled = 1">
                <xsl:attribute name="href">
                  <xsl:value-of select="@url"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:attribute name="href">#</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="onclick">return false</xsl:attribute>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:value-of select="@text" />
            <xsl:if test="node">
              <xsl:value-of select="$pointer" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
            </xsl:if>
          </a>
          <xsl:if test="node">
            <div class="sub">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="node">
                <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level + 1" />
              </xsl:apply-templates>

            </div>

          </xsl:if>
        </li>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$level=1">
        <ul class="megamenusubcontent">
          <li class="subheader">
            <h2>
              <a>
                <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="@enabled = 1">
                    <xsl:attribute name="href">
                      <xsl:value-of select="@url"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:attribute name="href">#</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="onclick">return false</xsl:attribute>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
                <xsl:value-of select="@text" />
              </a>
            </h2>
          </li>

          <xsl:if test="node">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node">
              <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level + 1" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
          </xsl:if>

        </ul>

      </xsl:when>

      <xsl:otherwise>
        <li class="sublink">
          <a>
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="@enabled = 1">
                <xsl:attribute name="href">
                  <xsl:value-of select="@url"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:attribute name="href">#</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="onclick">return false</xsl:attribute>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:value-of select="@text" />
          </a>
        </li>
        <xsl:if test="node">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node">
            <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level + 1" />
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Two questions really, 1) what xsl translation will I use to display a call to action 'View All' link at the bottom of my mega menu similar to the following:

[image]

2) where in the xslt template do I insert to have it appear at the bottom of all menu lists in the mega menu dropdown?

I have tried variations on the following but still nothing displays to screen:

```
  <xsl:template match="url">
    <a href="{.}">
      <xsl:value-of select="../view-all"/>
    </a>
  </xsl:template>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just having the last li in my mega menu as a 'View All' page and using css styled accordingly.